# How to suppress interactive grid popUp lov column's change event caused by changing the value of it's cascading parent column?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using `Oracle Apex 18.2`.

I have an interactive grid with two pop-Up lov's.

`Item_id` is non-enter-able and `expiry_date` is enter-able. 
**Edited:** There are stock items that have expiry dates and others that do not.

`Item_id` has an on-Change dynamic action that retrieves the minimum expiry date(if any) into `Expiry_date` column.

`Expiry_date` has another on-Change dynamic action that checks for on hand quantity of that item with that specific expiry date **Edited:** if any or with null expiry date through an Ajax call process.

As you already know, changing a parent pop-Up lov i.e `item_id` sets it's child(expiry_date) to null. Which causes the on-change dynamic action to fire with no intention from me to do so. How to suppress that dynamic action from firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround which is to set the "cascading parent item" attribute to "NULL" just to get the "items to submit" attribute displayed and be able to set it's value with the value you used to use in "cascading parent item" attribute which is "item_id". This way, changing item_id's value won't set expiry_date to null hence onChange da won't fire and the expiry_date popUp lov's query will be able to use item_id's value.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a condition on the DA fired by the change of Expiry_date to not fire if the value of the Expiry_Date is null.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Salim for your answer. Unfortunately, the dynamic action should also fire when expiry date is null because there are stock items that have expiry dates and others that not. Sorry, I did not mention that in the main post.